# How to disable an input element in Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Using [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework), the Form.Element.disable is said to be disabled the form as a whole. Is there any way to disable only one single input element at a time?

And when I try this:

```
$$('#signup .button')[0].disbled = false; ## didn't work
```

### Updated

Sorry for all. Actually it works. But I have defined a disabled style
in a stylesheet and the style doesn't got applied. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I guess it should either be disAbled = true, or enabled = false...

Comment: Regarding the disabled style, are you applying/toggling a disabled class on the form element?

Comment: No class necessary. All browsers support: `input[disabled] { .. }` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/MjKWr/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want the disable method.

http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Form/Element/disable/index.html

For example:

```
$(id).disable();
```

Comment: Link is dead, this is the new link: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Form/Element/disable/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$$('#signup .button').disable()
```

Or:

```
$(id_of_element).disable()
```

Or:

```
Form.Element.disable(id_of_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$$('#signup .button')[0].disable();
```